# Oracle ManagedDataAccess leaking memory?

Tags: .net, oracle, out-of-memory

I have a pretty simple C# method that reads rows from an Oracle DB

```
using ( OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader( ) )
{
   while ( reader.Read( ) )
   {
      //write row to an excel file using EPPlus
      DoRender( reader, sheet );
      ++rowCount;
   }
}
```

It works fine, but for some queries with > 120.000 rows (it's an export tool) the memory comsumption reaches > 1GB. Once the connection is closed, the memory is freed again.
Using the diagnostic tool, the component using the memory is easily identified:

Three snapshots from the diagnostic tool while the loop is executed:
[image: overview of the snapshots]
[image: first snapshot detail]
[image: third snapshot detail]

(Note that the details only show increments)
Of course, the excel writer needs some memory, but the OracleInternal is using most of it (a trend that continues throughout.
I am using 
.NET 4.6.1 64bit on Windows 10 64bit
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 12.1.2400 (via nuget, most current version)
EPPlus 4.0.5 (via nuget, most current version)

Any hint what I could do differently or if this really is an issue within die DataAccess component?

Comment: EPPlus keeps everything in memory, it can't write data as a stream, so it's most likely the issue, not ODAC. Just comment out the actual export and you should see ODAC easily fetches millions of rows via reader without any memory issue. Its buffer can be set for inline data, LONGs and LOBs separately. Default inline data buffer is just 128 kB.

Comment: Well, yes and no :-) But thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I do a reader.GetValue() and store it, this obviously pins the OracleBuffer containing the value. If I do a GetString(), memory consumption grows only a little (ok, the string has to be stored somewhere, but no OracleBuffers show up any more....

Comment: To be precise, it seems that doing GetValue() or GetString() on a Clob pins the OracleBuffer instance somehow. Obtaining the clob and reading the string from it solved the issue finally